# How to make a method singleton?

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I need to change this function to singleton pattern and idk how to do this.

```
  protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
      try {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.getDataSource();
        String SROP = "SROP";
        String prodUser = System.getenv("USERNAME");
        String prodPass = System.getenv("PASSWORD");
        String prodUrl = System.getenv("URL"); 
        
        config.setJdbcUrl(prodUrl != null ? prodUrl : "jdbc:postgresql:///" + SROP);
        config.setUsername(prodUser != null ? prodUser : SROP); 
        config.setPassword(prodPass != null ? prodPass : SROP); 
        
        // Initialize the connection pool using the configuration object.
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
  }
```

I'm new with design pattern.

Comment: Did you look up the singleton pattern already? There are a lot of tutorials and explanations which specifically use Java.

Comment: Also a function/method can't really be a singleton. An object can be made a singleton.

Comment: You're using spring, so why do you need a singleton pattern here? I would say it would be a bad practice. Just annotate with @Bean and it will create a singleton bean for you. Do you have a specific reason for using singleton design pattern?

Comment: @RahulKumar is because the connection pool is exploding... after some requests the hikari has 10 instances and crash. I want to get only one instance if already exists

Comment: Yes, so what you should be doing is have your method annotated with ```@Bean``` (also make your method public),  where you return an instance of your data source, and then use ```@Autowired``` wherever you need it. That way you can be sure there is just one instance of your data source in your entire application

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern:

> the singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single" instance

To change your code to implement the singleton pattern for the DataSource you can do something like:

```
private DataSource dataSource;

public DataSource getDatasource() {
   if (dataSource == null) {
      dataSource = selectAnyDataSource
   }
   return dataSource;
}

private DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to create one DataSource per spring context and you are using spring boot. You can do it with @Bean annotation.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {...}
```

Spring will automatically detect and reuse created data source. If you need somewhere data source you can inject it.

```
@Autowire
private DataSource dataSource;
```